# Uploading base64 through Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, base64, paperclip-validation

Paperclip is used for image uploads. Images uploaded in base64 form as follows:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :set_image
  attr_accessor :picture_data

  has_attached_file :image
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png)

  def set_image
    unless self.picture_data.nil?
      data = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(self.picture_data))
      self.image = data
      self.picture_data = nil
    end
  end

end
```

Paperclip correctly recognizes the content_type of the base64 passed but content_type validation is not happening. It saves whatever the file comes.

Can anyone please help me through this?!

Comment: Actually i am confuse at 'has_attached_file :image' and 'self.avatar = data' which field actually used for store image?

Comment: Sorry for the blender. Made the corrections.

Comment: Refer this link may be it's help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675747/use-paperclip-for-saving-base64-images-obtained-from-an-api

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `before_validation` callback instead of `before_save`.